# can't import sbt project with JDK 1.8?

Tags: java, sbt, java-8

I want to import `sbt` project under Intellij 13.1.

Current java version:

```
nazar@lelyak-desktop:~⟫ java -version
java version "1.8.0_05"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_05-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.5-b02, mixed mode)
```

During building project, I got error message:

[image]

Something is wrong with JDK 1.8?

I can't finish importing the project.

**UPDATE:**

I solved it by moving again to 1.7 version. It works fine.

Here is few tips about this issue [Cannot build with sbt](https://github.com/Bridgewater/scala-notebook/issues/24)

Any suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like your SBT uses [a Scala version that isn't compatible with Java 8](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/scala-user/Nzc2zUTyays). Try updating your SBT / Scala to a [newer version](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/liftweb/h84bWMHMyCM) and it should work again.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using sbt version 0.13.7 on Mac OS 10.10.2 with Java 1.8. I ran into the same problem and solved it with setting the 'java-home' option for sbt in the /usr/local/etc/sbtopts file. Specifically, I added this line to /usr/local/etc/sbtopts:

```
-java-home /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_51.jdk/Contents/Home
```

I did not need to change any sbt startup script or anything else.